# Why angular `ng-repeat` have different checkbox differentiate behavior then listing out checkbox manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

If I list out checkboxes manually

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkState"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkState"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Checking one checkbox checks all of the checkbox.

But if I use ng-repeat

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="elem in someArray">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkState"  />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Checking one checkbox only checks one of them

Is there a reason for this? From the DOM they both looks the same.

Comment: ng-repeat has its own scope

Comment: This is something you have to watch out when you start learning angularjs, scope works the same as inheritance in javascript, if you do a variable assignment in the child scope, it will shadow the parent, you can read more from [the angular github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#JSproto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue relates to the angular's `scope`. Each angular application has by default one root scope. It can however have multiple child scopes.

Some built in directives create new child scopes. `ng-repeat` is an example of this. Every element inside this directive has its own scope. When these scopes are created, they are automatically added as children of the parent scope.

This creates a tree structure similar to the DOM

```
rootScope
  - childScope
  - childScope
  - childScope
```

To see this in action, check out your browser's HTML. It will look something like this

```
<div>
  <li ng-repeat="elem in someArray" class="ng-scope ng-binding">elem 1
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkState"  />
  </li>
  <li ng-repeat="elem in someArray" class="ng-scope ng-binding">elem 1
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkState"  />
  </li>
</div>
```

Notice that each ng-repeat element has an `ng-scope` and an `ng-binding` class.

> The directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Every template item, in this case every `li` element has its own scope.

The directive uses `$watchCollection` to detect changes in the collection. ng-repeat makes the following changes to the DOM

- When a new item is added, a new instance of the template is added to the DOM
- When an item is removed, its template instance is removed from the DOM
- When items are reordered, their templates are reordered by the DOM

Here's the official documentation for Angular

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: This is good information and well explained, but lacks the critical explanation of why binding to the same `checkState` property in different child scopes doesn't just update that property on the parent scope. (Short answer: Look up the "Dot Rule").

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the `ng-repeat` example, even though the models all have the same name, they are each bound to a different scope.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)